# Build an autoresponder in Tawk.to

Tags: chatbot, tawk.to

We are using tawk.to in our company and are relatively happy with it. Unfortunately, we sometimes get into the situation where nobody is available to respond (this is not predictable). And so we want to create a basic autoresponder, that basically just gives the user a selection of topics and then responds with a link depnding on the user questions keywords. So I guess my question is, is it possible to create a chatbot in tawk.to that automatically activates after a certain time? That can receive a list of conversation and choose to enter one?
I have not found any information about this on their website, so can it be done?